# Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources' Crunching Cruncher…png failed

Tags: android

AAPT err(833489116): /home/pankaj/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

my gradel is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comproject.deltastara.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, but "png failed" sounds like an incorrect 9-patch to me.

Comment: yes same problem here but when i run this project in other android studio it run successful run this type of error is showing    :app:mergeDebugResources      AAPT err(255699918): /home/pankaj/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

installing lib32z1 resolved the issue. For the sake of clearity, I ran the following in the terminal

$sudo apt-get install lib32z1